# Still can't install pygame on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, pygame

I've tried three different ways. The most recent was following instructions here: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu

But when I type in the first line

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial python-dev python-numpy ffmpeg \
```

I am told that

```
E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate.
```

I continue on with the instructions and I am later told that some of the dependencies are missing (even though those are the ones I had attempted to install moments ago).

Then when I put in

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

it tells me

```
src/_pygame.h:80:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/a/312977/306707

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this problem.  Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

If that doesn't work you could try reinstalling python.  The following command line will remove all python modules and reinstall python.  After that try the command above again.  If you have any other downloaded python modules or idles you will need to reinstall them.

```
sudo apt-get purge python && sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Comment: Don't delete python, which will probably break things in ubuntu.